# Connect Excel with MySQL in debian

Tags: mysql, linux, excel, debian

We have a debian server, and there is a mysql db in it.

What i want to do is to connect the db from excel(office2010) on every users' computer(Windows 7).

Does anyone have a good tutorial or advices?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> http://www.enduserguides.com/software/office/mso/eug_mysqlodbc.html

This is the best tutorial I found